# React Native x OneSignal do not display notification

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, notifications, onesignal

I'm building an app in React Native and I'm currently implementing notifications using OneSignal.

I receive notifications efficiently but I don't want it to be displayed on the screen when received.

I read about a `shown` boolean value in the notification data but I don't know how nor where I can set it to `false` (currently it's always `true`, the default value).

I'm firing notifications from my node.js server, directly by making a POST request to https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications, sending JSON data (with `app_id`, `included_segments` fields, etc). I guess that's where I need to specify that I don't want the notification to be displayed, but I don't know how to do so and adding a `shown`field with `false` as a value in my request payload doesn't change a thing.

I'm also using OneSignal templates, configured in their web app. I thought it would be here, but I can't find a way to configure that specific need there.

Answer (score 2):

if you're using android you can set `OneSignal.inFocusDisplaying(2);` in the `componentWillMount()` or whatever function your invoking the One Signal Listeners in ..